# check not null for list in a list at specific index

Tags: c#

How do I access `list2` in `list1` below and check `IsnotNull` in an Assert

```
List<Object> list1= new List<Object>();

List<int> list2= new List<int>();

list1.add(someValue);
list1.add(list2);

Assert.IsNotNull(list1[1]..??);
```

Comment: `list1[1]` is how you would access `list2`.  It isn't clear what your issue is.

Comment: Why do you stuff disparate elements in one and the same list to begin with? That is the absence of software design and the absence of even the semblance of a data model. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how:

```
((List<int>)list1[1]).<something>
```

But please use some decent variable names. Also, a `List<Object>` is a huge code-smell.

Comment: This worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

@RobIII shows in his answer how you can cast the `object` value to a `List<int>`; however, the real question is, how do you know what is contained at which position in `list1`?  You will end up in a code similar to this one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++) {
    object item = list1[i];
    switch (item)
    {
        case int x:
            // do some thing with x
            break;
        case string s:
            // do some thing with s
            break;
        case IList list:
            // do some thing with list
            break;
        ....
    }
}
```

This is going to become tedious.

A better approach is to work in an object oriented manner. Example

```
public abstract class Property
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract void DoSomething();
}

public abstract class Property<T> : Property
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class StringProperty : Property<string>
{
    public override void DoSomething() =>
        Console.WriteLine($"String of length {Value?.Length}");
}

public class IntListProperty : Property<List<int>>
{
    public override void DoSomething() =>
        Console.WriteLine($"Int list has {Value?.Count} items");
}
```

Now you can write

```
var list1 = new List<Property>{
    new StringProperty { Name = "string property", Value = "hello" },
    new IntListProperty { Name = "Int list", Value = new List<int>{ 2, 3, 5, 7 } }
};

for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++) {
    Property prop = list1[i];
    Console.Write(prop.Name); Console.Write(": "); 
    prop.DoSomething();
}
```

This is called polymorphism. This means multi-shaped. You have properties of different shape, but all of them have a `Name` and a `DoSomething` method. You can call this method on properties of different type, and delegate the different things to do to these very properties. Each one of them know what it has to do.